# Problem with memory leak on iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I have a strange problem with a memory leak (the only one ;-) ) in my iPhone app:

[alt text http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/8530/bildschirmfoto20091105u.png](http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/8530/bildschirmfoto20091105u.png)

I don't know where I have to look for the cause of this leak... the strange thing is that this, exactly this leak also shows up if I create a new navigation-based app and just run it without any changes. I'm testing it in the simulator BTW because I don't have my developer certificate until now. 
Has anybody an idea what could be the cause of this leak?

Comment: See this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250666).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is not perfect and sometimes has leaks in the code.  If all your app is leaking is 256 **BYTES** then I think you will just be wasting your time trying to track it down.  My advice is to forget about it.