# How UIWindow#addSubview can make memory leak?

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I started to learn using Instrument, but I cannot figure it out.
After I start my application, the UI shows up, I do nothing and after few seconds I can see memory leak detected:
[image]

When I have a look at the second leak I can see the following stack:
[image]

When I double click on the cell related to my code I can see that it is pointing to the following line of code:

```
[window addSubview:newPostUIViewController.view];
```

from the method:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
//creating view controller
newPostUIViewController = [[NewPostUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewPostView" bundle:nil]; 
newPostUIViewController.title = @"Post it!";
[window addSubview:newPostUIViewController.view];

// Override point for customization after application launch
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I wonder, how this can be a reason of a leak?  I release newPostUIViewController in the dealloc method of PostItAppDelegate class.

Any ideas how this could be explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250666/iphone-sdk-utility-application-template-has-leak) allows to say that this is Simulator problem, not the code problem.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an `autorelease` or `release` to balance your `init`.  Just in case you haven't read through it already, have a look at the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) is a great help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, I release both newPostUIViewController and window in the dealloc method of PostItAppDelegate. Should I call the release in some other place?

Comment: @Jakub can you post some more code showing how you use the controller?  It's possible that the controller has an extra retain, but not on that line.